# Git commit -a error

Tags: git

I'm trying to commit some git changes but when I run:

```
git commit -a
```

it returns

```
gvim -f: gvim: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'gvim -f'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I am a noob and I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about this but looking at the [Git documentation for default editor](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), it falls back to vi when no editor is set.  As the error suggested, you can pass a `-m` option so you dont have to use an editor.

```
git commit -a -m 'committing all files'
```

Comment: Thanks; That did the trick. I didn't realize that all of my previous commits included a -m message. When I added a filler message in the commit command, that fixed it. Hoorah!

Answer (score 3):

You have configured `gvim` as the default editor in `git` but you don't have it installed in your system. You've 3 choices:

1) install the  [gvim](http://www.vim.org)  editor on your system

2) change the default editor of `git` with:

```
git config --global core.editor "path_of_your_favourite_text_editor"
```

3) keep on commiting without using a text-editor (not really a good solution)

```
git commit -a -m 'commit message'
```

Comment: Hoorah! I actually did have Vim/Gvim installed so I tried your third option and that worked.